# Scraping table from a webpage using Selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I need to navigate to a page, select two options from select tag and click on search button.
The navigation is already done by me.
Once the search is completed a table appears, I need to scrap that table using pandas. How do I do it?

Used the pandas pd.read_html, but it won't give output as the url that I provide is of base page. I need to select options and click on search, only then the table appears. And the url doesn't change after hitting search.

Comment: not enough details in your question but try df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]

Comment: On the webpage I need to select a particular date and set a status from select tag. I cannot add just based page url, as it won't work unless I filter the data and search for it. Once I search by adding the filters only then the table is displayed on the page.

Comment: See: [How do I do X?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) The expectation on SO is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]